# Pegar o id do array dentro da sessão

Tags: php

Tenho a sessão `$_SESSION['linha_pedagio'][]` disposta assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => CGO - RJA (via Magé)
            [2] => 96.30
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 9681
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => RJA - CPQ
            [2] => 224.70
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 493
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => RJA - BMA
            [2] => 72.00
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 5270
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => BMA X B. PIRAI
            [2] => 20.00
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 5027
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => CGO - RJA (via Magé)
            [2] => 96.30
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 4493
        )

)
```

Porém preciso excluir um dos arrays da $_SESSION, que sejam o 0, 2 ou 5.

Eu utilizei o `unset($_SESSION['linha_pedagio'][$id]);` mas coleto o valor errado para a variável `$id`,

Há uma forma de pegar esse id principal?

Valores: 0, 2, 3, 4 e 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode "capturar" esse id da seguinte forma:

```
foreach($_SESSION['linha_pedagio'] as $id => $objeto){
    if($id == 0 || $id == 2 || $id == 5){
        unset($_SESSION['linha_pedagio'][$id]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Julyano... fazendo isso `$id => $objeto` ainda posso utilizar os outros dados do array né?
Ex: `$rota = $objeto[1]; $valor = $objeto[2];`

Comment: Sim, correto @thiagofred